# Run a build system with Grunt

Tags: node.js, build, npm, gruntjs, system

I'm trying to run a build system with grunt, but when i try to run the command  `npm install -g grunt-cli` i get the errors in the pictures attached, i have install `grunt-cli` as well but i'm really  lost with all that errors i got.I'm using Mac OS X,version 10.10.5 27-inch,processor 2.8 GHz intel i5. Also i have read an article how to install node and npm in mac and there i found about  Homebrew but when i check for node and npm they was installed already in my mac so i'm not really sure if the errors i get has any relation with node and npm version?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run with `sudo`

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

You may need to enter the password of the machine.

**Explanation**
If you see the errors on the terminal it reads:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied
```

On a high level, it basically means that while executing the command the current user did not have the privilege/access to write in the dir `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Using `sudo` elevates the user's privilege.

EDIT:

if it still doesn't work try this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

then try installing `grunt-cli` again

Comment: thanks a lot, i was losing my mind wit such an easy step :D